# How to include a variable in a jsp tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to dynamically include a jsp file with the following code:

```
<%@include file="menus/top/${user.roleId}.jsp" %>
```

Here, the variable `user.roleId` is an `int` which is being set in my struts2 action. I'm able to display it with the following:

`<s:property value="user.roleId" />`

I want the files `menus/top/1.jsp`, or `menus/top/2.jsp` etc to be included dynamically, depending on the roleId of the currently logged in user. But I'm getting the following exception with the include tag:

```
Exception Name: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "menus/top/${user.roleId}.jsp" not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `<s:include>` http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/include.html

Comment: @coding_idiot correct.. if you wanna post that as answer, i'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%@include file="menus/top/${user.roleId}.jsp" %>
```

Use [struts2 include tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/include.html) instead

```
<s:include file="menus/top/%{user.roleId}.jsp"/>
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html) clearly says include directive is not processed and hence, can't have expressions that needs runtime evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

`<%@include %>` is a *static* include directive. It's thus used at compile time, when the JSP is compiled into a class. This implies that runtime variables can't be used inside this directive.

You're looking for `<jsp:include>`, which includes a resource dynamically, at runtime. Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, and can I include the variable name using `${user.roleId}` as I'm doing, or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: You can, if you use a dynamic include.

Comment: `<jsp:include page="menus/top/${user.roleId}.jsp" />` is giving me another error: 'Exception Name: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page`. How do I have to modify this?

Comment: Ask another question, containing the code, the expected result, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: This question is about how to include this file, so I don't think this merits another question.

Comment: Fyi removing the `${user.roleId}` makes it work, so the error seems to be in that part.

Answer (score 1):

use `<c:import>` tag. As it is used for dynamic include in JSTL.

where `c` :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: Changing the line `<c:import url="menus/top/${user.roleId}.jsp" />` to `<c:import url="menus/top/1.jsp" />` makes it work fine.

Comment: The variable `user.roleId` is being set by Struts, its not actually a JSP variable.. could that be why this line doesn't work with a variable?

Comment: why cant you frame the whole ulr separately by joining an d evaluating the expression and add it to `import`

Comment: can you show me an example of how to do it? i'm a bit new to jsp

Comment: @ClickUpvote evaluate `user.roleId` than add this to `menus/top/` also add `.jsp` than you put this string with `url`. Will it not work?

Comment: I don't really know how to evaluate it and add it to `menus/top` etc, can you show me how its done? Right now, in order to display the value of `user.roleId` I have to do: `<s:property value="user.roleId" />`. Here `s.property` is a Struts tag.